# Asking manager to keep an eye out for opportunities

Tags: telecommute

Few years back I decided to leave a big successful company where I really enjoyed working. I left on good terms (because of family reasons) and moved back to my home country.

Because I really didn't want to leave, I asked for telecommuting options first, but I was told no such option was available.

Would it be inappropriate to ask my former manager (which I was on good terms with) to keep an eye out for any future telecommuting positions? I don't want to look like I'm begging for work.

Just to clarify when I left, they told me, that if I ever were to come back, they would find a position for me. Also there are people who are telecommuting, but from the same country and they do very specific jobs.

Comment: Can't hurt to ask, as far as I can see. Might not help either, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Would it be inappropriate to ask my former manager (which I was on good terms with) to keep an eye out for any future telecommuting positions?

It's perfectly appropriate, though you want to be careful how you phrase your question as, like you say, you don't want to come across as begging for work.

Something like the following should be fine.

> When we originally parted ways we looked into the possibility of me continuing to work remotely but that didn't turn out to be a viable option at the time. Since [*reasons why you enjoyed working with that manager/team/company*], I wonder if you [*or the company*] would be open to revisiting that idea?

If you know for a fact that they currently have employees working remotely *full-time*, you can add that as another reason. Consider prefacing your email with generic pleasantries like you would use for any business contact, but don't bother doing so if you don't have anything substantial to add or if you know that your old manager prefers shot and direct communication.

The only time it would be inappropriate is if they gave you valid reasons why telecommuting wasn't an option at the time and you know that it's unlikely that those reasons changed. If the time zone difference between the company and your country is more than a few hours that could be one such reason.

The best way of contacting the manager would probably be via email since it avoids putting him on the spot as a phone call would do. While this doesn't apply to your situation, if you still have a very good or close relationship and occasionally meet up or call each you'd just bring it up during that check-in and ask him to think it over.

Comment: Would it be fine to write the manager directly to his work email address or is this considered inappropriate?

Comment: @Zikato It seems the most appropriate choice since you know him well and you have a work-related question. I'm not sure what the alternative would be, sending an application to HR? Email has the advantage over a phone call or meeting in person (if that were an option) in that it won't put him on the spot.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thank you, your answer has been most helpful.